# How to update JavaScript asset map to return a dynamic field?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mapping

How can I update the function I use with myAssetMap to handle cases when a match is not found? Given:

```
const myAssetMap = {
  Generic: {
    name: 'Generic',
    bkgHex: '#eee',
    fontHex: '#aaa',
  },
  Specific1: {
    name: 'Specific1',
    bkgHex: '#131sde',
    fontHex: '#FFF',
  },
  Specific2: {
    name: 'Specific2',
    bkgHex: '#131sde',
    fontHex: '#FFF',
  },
 ...
```

I can find values from myAssetMap like so:

```
const getAsset = (name, type) => {
  return return myAssetMap[name][type];
}

console.log( getAsset('Specific1', 'name') );
console.log( getAsset('Specific2', 'name') );
```

This works great. but I need Generic to be dynamic.

In the case where the asset is not found, example:

```
console.log( getAsset('XXXXXX', 'name') );
```

How can I have the above use Generic.bkgHex and Generic.fontHex, but have Generic.name be whatever is passed to the getAsset func. For example, the desired result would be:

```
console.log( getAsset('XXXXXX', 'name') );
$ XXXXXX
console.log( getAsset('XXXXXX', 'bkgHex') );
$ #eee
console.log( getAsset('XXXXXX', 'fontHex') );
$ #aaa
```

Comment: This is what you want: `getAsset('XXXXXX', 'name') = XXXXXX`??

Comment: yes is it, right now it returns 'Generic'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this ternary condition:**

```
myAssetMap[name] ? (myAssetMap[name][type] || myAssetMap['Generic'][type]) : (type === 'name' ? name : myAssetMap['Generic'][type])
```

```js
const myAssetMap = {
  Generic: {
    name: 'Generic',
    bkgHex: '#eee',
    fontHex: '#aaa',
  },
  Specific1: {
    name: 'Specific1',
    bkgHex: '#131sde',
    fontHex: '#FFF',
  },
  Specific2: {
    name: 'Specific2',
    bkgHex: '#131sde',
    fontHex: '#FFF',
  }
};

const getAsset = (name, type) => {
  return myAssetMap[name] ? (myAssetMap[name][type] || myAssetMap['Generic'][type]) : (type === 'name' ? name : myAssetMap['Generic'][type]);
}

console.log(getAsset('XXXXXX', 'name'));
console.log(getAsset('XXXXXX', 'bkgHex'));
console.log(getAsset('XXXXXX', 'fontHex'));
console.log(getAsset('HELLO', 'name'));
console.log(getAsset('HELLO', 'bkgHex'));
console.log(getAsset('HELLO', 'fontHex'));
console.log(getAsset('Specific1', 'name'));
console.log(getAsset('Specific2', 'name'));
```

Comment: @AnApprentice you change it to `if-else`.